# ValidationMessageFor printing default message and not the custom one

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to print my custom message through mvc model using jquery validation but still it is printing the default message and not the one which i have specified

code:

Model
     public class Task_runsModel             //user use this to add tasks and comments
    {
        public int Task_Run_Id { get; set; }

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You can't leave this empty.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public int Project_Id { get; set; }
    public string start_time { get; set; }
    public string end_time { get; set; }
    public int dead { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You can't leave this empty.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "You can't leave this empty.")]
    public int Task_Id { get; set; }

    public int Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime timestamp_dtm { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You can't leave this empty.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string status { get; set; }

    public decimal duration { get; set; }

    public string comment1 { get; set; }
    public string Task_Name { get; set; }
    public string Project_Name { get; set; }



}
```

Html:

```
<div id="add_task_dialog_box" class="hide">
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveEvent", "Base", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form_data", @class = "form-horizontal", style = "display: none;" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <div>
            <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding-right " style="font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 13px; text-align: left; font-family: Arial Unicode MS;">
                Project Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.Project_Id, db.getProjects(a), "--Select--", new { style = "width:200px;", id = "myproject" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding-right ">
            </label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.Project_Id, String.Empty, new { @class = "id_form_valid error" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="space-6">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding-right " style="font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 13px; text-align: left; font-family: Arial Unicode MS;">
                Select Task</label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.Task_Id, db.getTasks(a, c), "--Select--", new { style = "width:200px;", id = "mytask" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding-right ">
            </label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <div class="clearfix validation-summary-valid">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.Task_Id, String.Empty, new { @class = "id_form_valid error" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="space-6">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding-right " style="font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 13px; text-align: left; font-family: Arial Unicode MS;">
                Status</label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.status, db.getStatus(), "---Select---", new { style = "width:200px", id = "taskstatus", name = "taskname" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 no-padding-right ">
            </label>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.status, String.Empty, new { @class = "id_form_valid error" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <div id="chatarea" class="dropdown-toggle" style="float: left; padding-left: 20px;
                overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: auto;">
            </div>
            <b style="float: right; padding-right: 20px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"
                id="DisplayComment"></b>
        </div>
        <div id="textareadiv" style="padding-top: 3px;">
            <span class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" style="padding-left: 12px; width: inherit;">@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Task_runsModel.comment1, new { id = "comment", ariahidden = "true", placeholder = "Write comment", @class = "form-control wp-editor-area", cols = "65", rows = "3", style = " width: calc(100%);" })
            </span>
        </div>

    </fieldset>

 }
```

Comment: I would recommend improving the code formatting for the question and removing anything that is not necessary such as the commented out code blocks.

Comment: Is it ok now? can anyone please help me?

Comment: Further suggestions: i) You still have code leaking outside of the code block for the model, ii) You have lines of white space that could be reduced to a single line. iii) There is probably more code than required to allow someone to answer the question. For example, do you need the duration and comment1 fields in the model and do you need the anti-forgery token helper call in the view? iv) Which field in particular are you having issues with?  v) What is the default message you are currently receiving? vi) What have you tried so far?

Comment: I believe that if your question is improved and is succinct, then you will improve your chances of getting a response and will leave it in a readable state to benefit others in the future.  Hope this helps.